# Switching Wordpress Themes results in blank page (Child Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress

While trying to fix some issue with Woocommerce, I switched between my Child Theme and the Parent Theme. The Child has been active for a while, with no issues so far. After switching back, it just shows a blank page on my localhost. I turned on the debug mode in the `wp-config.php` but there's no error shown.

The stylesheet is still active, so I suspect the error to be somehow related to PHP. I tried to use the parents `index.php` file, but that gives me a blank site as well. When I switch to the Parent Theme, everything works just normal.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the site back up?

Edit:

Error Log from `debug.log`

```
[11-Sep-2018 20:39:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() in /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/header/site-branding.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/template.php(690): require()
#1 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/template.php(647): load_template('/Users/vincent/...', false)
#2 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/general-template.php(155): locate_template(Array, true, false)
#3 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/header/header-image.php(18): get_template_part('template-parts/...', 'branding')
#4 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/template.php(690): require('/Users/vincent/...')
#5 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/we in /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/header/site-branding.php on line 33
[11-Sep-2018 20:39:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() in /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/header/site-branding.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/template.php(690): require()
#1 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/template.php(647): load_template('/Users/vincent/...', false)
#2 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/general-template.php(155): locate_template(Array, true, false)
#3 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/header/header-image.php(18): get_template_part('template-parts/...', 'branding')
#4 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-includes/template.php(690): require('/Users/vincent/...')
#5 /Users/vincent/Documents/work/we in /Users/vincent/Documents/work/websites/piper+speck/local/piper-speck/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/template-parts/header/site-branding.php on line 33
```

Comment: can you access your error log? looks like you have white screen of death.

Comment: @unixmiah I activated the error log, it's in the post now.

Comment: this theme requires wordpress version WordPress 4.7 what is your wordpress version?

Comment: My version is 4.9.8. It's been that version since the beginning. The theme worked with this version before.

Comment: you need to resolve the error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() thats why you're getting a black screen. The biggest cause seems there is an issue with updates using the latest versions.